# Combine separate entities in one such that they are not tightly coupled

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, abstraction

I am initiating a process to create something that process is further divided into 4 step and each step represents a class , i have separated all 4 step by considering Single responsibility principle.each class is composed of set get methods . so far my code is

```
public class manipulator{

private A a;
private B b;
private C c;
private D d;

public manipulator(){
a= new A();
b= new B();
c= new C();
d= new D();
}
//getters and setters of all 4steps
}
```

manipulator is main class that contains all 4 steps , each step in constructor  is further initiated but i am considering this as tightly coupled system  as there are initiating inside constructor . How should i engage interface in it to provide abstraction and to make it loosely coupled.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this (I am not exactly sure what programming language you are using, so treat this as pseudo-code):

```
class Manipulator {

    private List steps;

    public manipulator() {
        this->steps = new List();
    }

    public add(Step step) {
        this->steps->append(step);
        return this; // you can chain add() calls
    }

    public run() {
        foreach (step in this->steps) {
            step->run();
        }
    }

}
```

Here you have an array for your steps, you don't depend on A, B, C, D classes. You don't limit yourself to only 4 steps.

The steps itself should have a base class or an interface, most probably they anyway have a lot of common things:

```
class Step { // or abstract class Step or interface Step

    public run() {
    }
}

class StepA extends Step { ... }

class StepB extends Step { ... }

class StepC extends Step { ... }

class StepD extends Step { ... }
```

Now you configure your manipulator with steps:

```
manipulator = new Manipulator()
manipluator->add(new StepA())->add(new StepB())->add(new StepC())->add(new StepD())
manipulator->run()
```

Few more notes to consider:

- "getters and setters of all 4steps" - most probably you don't need them and in general having getters / setters for everything is not good. Search for something like ["why getters and setters are bad"](https://www.google.com.ua/search?num=100&espv=2&q=google%20copy%20the%20search%20link&oq=google%20copy%20the%20search%20link)
- check this post, ["Your coding conventions are hurting you"](http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html), having classes like "Manipulator" might be not the best idea (although I don't know the details, so I may be mistaken)

Comment: well said @Boris Serebov .but how should i combine all these step in one interface soo that i inject interface in manipulator and when ever i want to get stepA it should be like Istep,getStepA() etc etc. i am totally confused related to this plz help me in this regard

Comment: @Mark I am not sure I understand your question. The `Manipulator` in my example combines the steps, it has the list of them in `this->steps`, so it can access any step. Based on your comment, it looks like you want one more class here, some `StepsCollection`, so you can add steps to the collection and then pass the collection to your manipulator. In this case you just rename the `Manipulator` in my example into `StepsCollection` and add another `Manipulator` class which will contain the collection. If that's not what you want, please update your question with more details and code examples.